# How to show certificate and signature information attached to a Windows binary?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, digital-signature

How do I use OpenSSL to show the certificate and signature information attached to a binary (e.g. windows exe or msi)?

I know that it's possible to read certificates directly from certificate files like `openssl x509 -in cert.crt -text` and that it's also possible to verify files (what is not what i want because i do not have a certificate to do so), but how to check if a file has a digital signature and get additional info if so.

I also checked Stackoverflow and Google for more info, but all searches brought me to pages on how to "verify binarys" and not "get them"

Comment: Did you check those pages anyway? I'd expect the "getting" part to be part of the process. So after "getting" the signature you should be able to examine it closer. That would be my thinking. In addition consider using the apostrophe to `mark` lines like the openssl one differently.

Comment: I _think_ the term of interest is *Authenticode*. That's Microsoft PFX signing applied to PE and PE+ files. With that said, here's a good tutorial on _signing_ from Mozilla: [Signing an executable with Authenticode](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Signing_an_executable_with_Authenticode). Finding the verification commands is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, it seems that openssl simply is not able to "get" a certificate / Authenticode the easy way just by offering the binary. In the end, I found a python module thats capable of extracting authenticode certificates -> [pefile](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile). So I decided to use that since I need a automatable soloution anyway. Also [Windows Signtool](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/signcode-signtool-command-line.htm) should be capable of doing so which seems also to be aviable for [Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287960/signing-windows-application-on-linux-based-distros) (when working on non windows platforms).